# How do I get the array to append the objects in the database in order?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am appending the username column and the image column to two different arrays from parse. I am then putting them into the collection view. I am anticipating that the username in the nameArray corresponds to the imageArray, but majority of the time they are in the wrong order. How do I get them to append into the array in the right order? i.e. User 1 has picture 1, user 2 has picture 2. username array = [User 1, User 2]. image array = [picture 1, picture 2].

```
func getFriendPicandName(){

    let imagequery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    imagequery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {( objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       // for object in objects!{
            var user = PFUser.currentUser()
            let relation = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
            relation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                for object in objects!{
                let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
                userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if(error == nil){
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        self.arrayOfFriends.append(image!)
                        print(self.arrayOfFriends)

                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
            })
        }

        }
    }



    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
            let relations = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
            relations.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]
                for i in 0...(objectIDs.count){
                self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
                print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)

            }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
        }



    })


   }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfFriendsNames.count
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: friendcellView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! friendcellView




    cell.friendname.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item]
    cell.friendpic.image =  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item]
    cell.friendpic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.friendpic.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.friendpic.clipsToBounds = true



    return cell
}
```

Comment: I think it's better if can get name and pic in the same function. Someone please helps him

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestion. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I mean you just need `    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({` one time. As you can see, you query the same table. Just different the key `"ProPic"` and `"username"`, you should put them in the same block `let relation = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
            relation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call your query twice, I would imagine your for loop to look something like this:

```
for object in objects!{
    let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
    userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if(error == nil){
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        self.arrayOfFriends.append(image!) // Add image here
        print(self.arrayOfFriends)

    }

    self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String) // Add Name here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about swift but I combined you both function into one...i hope it will help you...

```
func getFriendPic(){

    let imagequery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    imagequery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {( objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // for object in objects!{
        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        let relation = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
        relation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]
            for i in 0...(objectIDs.count){
                self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
                print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)

            }

            for object in objects!{
                let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
                userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if(error == nil){
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        self.arrayOfFriends.append(image!)
                        print(self.arrayOfFriends)

                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
            }

        }
    }
}
```